# Changing Layout in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I am trying to create simple navigation for an android app.

I have a main layout that contains the navigation buttons and then I include this with the layout's that are to be loaded using:

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_main" />
```

I then call the layouts, from the navigation buttons:

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.navigation_home:
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.home_layout);
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_dashboard:
                textMessage.SetText(Resource.Layout.dashboard_layout);
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_settings:
                
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout_settings);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However, when I run it and you click one of the navigation links, the first one loads, and the subsequent ones do not load.

It seemingly is like it's not refreshing after loading the new layout.

Comment: You would do that with Fragments and through Fragment Transactions instead of swapping the ContentView.

Comment: Is there no way to do it with ContentView?

Comment: It is not recommended, no.

Comment: You are not helping yourself here. The answer is. No it is not possible using `SetContentView` because you are replacing the entire view. If you are having issues with understanding how FragmentTransactions work, create a new question describing those issues and what you have tried.

Comment: I mean, I googled this and didn't find any suitable solution. I thought that was the basic idea of Stackoverflow, to provide assistance to whomever asks and hopefully thereby stop people in future asking the same questions. But yeah this place used to be good.

Comment: You probably googled the wrong thing. There are plenty of good resources on how to set up a NavigationView triggering FragmentTransactions when an item has been selected. As I said, if you have any issues with _that_ particular problem, create a new question asking about those specifics. For this question, it cannot be answered with anything else than what has been commented already.